# Are with WebMercator the X and Y extents identical?

Tags: web-mercator

I am calculating the tile coordinates in a WebMercator projection at different zoom levels and have the following problem:

Cartopy suggests that the projection extent in meters is slightly different in the X and Y direction:

```
In [67]:     extent_x = ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR.x_limits[1] - ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR.x_limits[0]
   ....:     extent_y = ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR.y_limits[1] - ccrs.GOOGLE_MERCATOR.y_limits[0]
   ....: 

In [68]: extent_x
Out[68]: 40075016.685578488

In [69]: extent_y
Out[69]: 40075016.685578495

In [70]: extent_x - extent_y
Out[70]: -7.4505805969238281e-09
```

While [this reference](http://www.maptiler.org/google-maps-coordinates-tile-bounds-projection/) (see the `__init__` and `MetersToPixels` functions in the script at the end) suggests that extent is equal in both directions:

```
self.initialResolution = 2 * math.pi * 6378137 / self.tileSize
...
res = self.Resolution( zoom )
px = (mx + self.originShift) / res
py = (my + self.originShift) / res
```

Which is right? Is the discrepancy in X and Y extent that results from using the cartopy definition merely a floating-point approximation issue or real?

If it is an floating point artifact, is there a way to obtain correct X and Y extents from cartopy?

Comment: Web Mercator is a *Mercator* projection -- distance is not reliable in any dimenson, much less equivalent in X and Y at any location

Answer (score 1):

See this image:

[image].

As you can see the distance between the latitudes increases in the direction of the poles. So how should the resolution in this direction be equal? A cm at the pole-position in Y-direction is surely much more then a cm at the Equator. To be more precise Web-Mercator (as most Mercator-projections) cannot project the poles at all because they are infinitely far away.

However this does also not apply to the X-resolution as the total length of the full circle at latitude 80 (see north of Greenland for instance) is much smaller than the Equator, isn´t it? Only exception from this rule is the Equator itself where we surely have this equality on resolution in direction of X and that therefore has no further graphical distortion (except from the scale of the map itself).